# How to convert a varchar data type field to a timestamp with time zone type field in redshift?

Tags: amazon-redshift, timestamp-with-timezone, amazon-redshift-spectrum

I have a table where the `timestamp` is stored as a `varchar`. I need to convert it to `timestamp` with `timezone` but every time I get **"Invalid Operation"** error.

The format of the field is:

```
2017-10-30 10:12:34:154 +1100
```

**I tried the following:**

```
'2017-10-30 10:12:34:154 +1100'::timestamptz
'2017-10-30 10:12:34:154 +1100'::timestamp
to_timestamp('2017-10-30 10:12:34:154 +1100')
to_date('2017-10-30 10:12:34:154 +1100')
to_timestamp(to_char('2017-10-30 10:12:34:154 +1100'))
```

*All gave an error like this:*

```
[Amazon](500310) Invalid operation: function to_timestamp(character varying) does not exist;
```

Can somebody please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the benefit of all, here's how I solved my question. Basically, the problem was that the acceptable syntax for timestamp with timezone in redshift was '2017-10-30 10:12:34.154 +1100' where the milliseconds was after the '.' and not after ':'. Although, I am not sure of this. But this seemed to be the only problem from the redshift documentation and playing around a bit.

The substr_replace didn't work in my case since the length of the date and time keeps varying like these two -

```
'2017-10-30 10:12:34:154 +1100' , '2017-10-3 5:12:34:154 +1100'
```

So, I split all three fields and added them back in proper syntax after removing milliseconds since I didn't need that.

```
(split_part(m.properties_date_time_tz,' ',1)||' '||substring(split_part(m.properties_date_time_tz,' ',2),0,length(split_part(m.properties_date_time_tz,' ',2))-3)||' '||split_part(m.properties_date_time_tz,' ',3))::timestamptz
```

where properties_date_time_tz had a value like '2017-10-30 10:12:34:154 +1100'

Answer (score 1):

To Redshift's to_timezone does not support offsets so you need to mangle it as follows:

```
select DATEADD('ms',
           (SUBSTRING('2017-10-30 10:12:34:154 +1100',21,3 ))::int,
           (SUBSTRING('2017-10-30 10:12:34:154 +1100', 0,20) + SUBSTRING('2017-10-30 10:12:34:154 +1100', 24,6))::timestamp)
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. I am getting an error like this: `[Amazon](500310) Invalid operation: "OF" not supported;`

Comment: apologies. please see above

Comment: Thanks alot @Tom. Your solution helped me in reaching to my final solution.